# Headers needed to display a base64 image with Perl?

Tags: perl, http, base64

So I'm trying to display an image with a http page like the ones you get with "View Image" on your browser. I got this far and I have no idea what else I have to do to get Firefox to read my goddamn image data.

```
open (my $fh, "<", "/where/the/base64_encoded_img/is");
local $/= undef;
my $image = <$fh>;
close $fh;
local $/= "\n";

use MIME::Base64;
my $alpha;
$alpha .= "Content-type: image/png;base64 \n"; #our image is a PNG
$alpha .= "Content-length: " . MIME::Base64::encoded_base64_length($image) . " \n\n  ";
$alpha .= " ";
#~ $alpha .= "<img src='$image'/>";
$alpha .= "$image";
print $alpha;
```

Consider that I tried both with and without the **"data:*our_data_type*;charset=utf-8;base64,"** string before the hashed image (This string is contained within the **$image** variable).

Comment: Is this a CGI script? There's no need to base64 an HTTP response that is an image. Just send the image! If you're sending a PNG directly in response to an HTTP request (and not embedding it in some HTML in the same response) then the `data:` URI scheme is irrelevant.

Comment: Does `$image` contain raw image data? Then you need to Base64-encode it before you output it.

Comment: I'm not an expert but I never saw your notation for Content-Type, with the base64 appended. I would have used a Content-Transer-Encoding instead to specify the base64 thing. Also, is your image already in base64 oin the file? If not, you will probably have problems.

Comment: A lot of the things in your code make no sense. If you want to include an inline-image inside of your HTML you don't need a header for the image, because the content type is `text/html` for your page and stuff in the middle of the page cannot have an additional HTTP header, as there is no second response. If you want that program to send a response with only an image, you can send it as binary, no need to encode it. In that case, you do need a header.

Comment: Also your newlines seem to be afraid of your other characters. They've set themselves off with a bunch of unnecessary spaces. The spaces that come after the double-newline are especially bad, since they become the first bytes of the alleged PNG. When you stick some spaces on the start of a PNG, it's not a PNG any more. Have a talk with your newlines about their claustrophobia.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley - It is a CGI script, and I was genuinely inspired to benchmark what'd be faster for a server, encoding a picture, keeping it as a text format & displaying it to a user. And the newlines - my apache usually gives me a 500 err unless I add/del a whitespace. 

at DavidVerdin -The first line, starting with $alpha is supposedly the header; since when I'm displaying regular html pages it works like a charm. The image itself has already been encoded, I'm only trying to get the black background & image in the middle, like what you get when you right-click over an image & view image

Answer (score 1):

HTTP transmits payloads as binary just fine. There is no way to use base64, nor is there a need for it.

Comment: So in any case, in order to display it, I must have it decoded?

Comment: I'm trying this due to the fact that css should be able to hold images in this format, I'm not sure if I add the same image, but not encoded, with **<img>** or with **background-image:** and then firefox (or any generic browser) will download it just once and cache it. Also trying to benchmark if it'll be faster to load images in this format from a DB; as a blob (normal image), or from the fs itself.

Answer (score 1):

Banish base64 from the project, and do this minimal version of your script:

```
open (my $fh, "<", "/where/the/img/is");

{
  local $/= undef;
  my $image = <$fh>;
  close $fh;
}

print "Content-Type: image/png\n\n";
print $image;
```

Note that the point of using `local` is that the previous value of the variable is automatically restored when the containing block ends. If you don't put it in a block, and manually restore the default value, `local` isn't doing anything for you.

Even this should be good enough:

```
print "Content-Type: image/png\n\n";
exec 'cat', '/where/the/img/is';
```

Answer (score -2):

```
my $image = <$fh>;
```

I don't recommend this. Use binary read.

Add a `content-transfer-encoding` header and you can send base64 or binary.
Turn off I/O caching (`$|`) or strange things can happen.

Comment: There is no "content-transfer-encoding" header field in HTTP.

Comment: enabling binmode on a base64 encoded image? I thought it's just text?